# Running Powershell Application on Other computers

Tags: powershell

I will try this again. I can only get my .exe to run on the computer which created it and select other ones. Even once a application has been built into an .exe is it necessary that the computer it is run on still has powershell studio? Right now the executable will only run on computers with powershell studio, I am not sure if it is because these other computers are lacking a library or something along those lines or if every computer that I want to run it needs powershell studio. This as I have asked around is actually an issue with other executables which have been made from powershell studio so the problem is not exclusive to my code, which if necessary I can show some of.  However I think it is more of an issue with the settings in the .exe builder which is something I am very new to and do not fully understand what or if I need to get it to work properly.I currently have left all the settings in the builder as the default settings so I am sure it is something in there that needs to be looked at I am just at a loss as for what.

Comment: I'm sure there are a lots of reasons why it wouldn't work on other computers, but there's far too little information in your question to know what's happening here.

Comment: My real question I guess first of all is if in order to run the executable does the computer also need to have powershell studio on that computer.  Right now only computers that have it can run it.

Comment: Do the machines that fail have powershell 4.0, or do you need to recompile it to run on powershell 2.0

Comment: The ones that run it have Powershell 2.0 for the most part but they only have the ISE not powershell studio which is where the script was made.

Comment: sapien does not need to be installed.   that is not the cause I assure you.  the default settings are specific to the machine that you compile on.  For example if you compile on x64 machine, it will default to x64, so maybe is that the problem ?

Comment: All of the computers which I am attempting to put it on are x64 including mine which I built it on.

Comment: The computer which it was built on is running Powershell 3.0 while the other computers I am trying to put it on are running Powershell 2.0. Could this be my problem? And if so would the best solution be to update all those other computers or is there a way which what I have already created can be run in 2.0?

Comment: you only need to recompile it for v2.0 powershell.   It's a little box on the ribbon that probably says `v3 - 64bit`, change that to `v2 -64bit` in the drop down list.   I'll post that as an answer later if it works.

Comment: This worked thanks.  I just need to fix my permissions and will be good to go, but this finally allowed it to popup on other computers thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not a problem, just recompile it targeting the lowest common denominator.   If you are on Powershell v3, but have some clients on v2, you'll need to recompile targeting v2.

To recompile, go into Sapien Studio and look for the drop down box on the ribbon, it probably says `v3 - 64bit`, change that to `v2 -64bit` and recompile.  Good luck.

Alternatively you could install powershell v3 on those other machines and not need to recompile.  That would also be the answer if you `have` to use a v3 cmdlet that simply does not exist in v2.

Noted:  Future readers may also run into issues with x86/x64 bitness and system32 folder, if you are getting redirected into syswow64 sandbox, recompile 2 versions, one for 32bit, one for 64.